# .\idea.bat works but not idea64.exe when running Intellij IDEA 64-bit

Tags: intellij-idea

So this issue happened after I was downloading CLion and Visual Studio Community 2015. As stated in the title, I am unable to open my Intellij IDEA or CLION using the shortcut or even double-clicking on the idea64.exe file. I am using windows 8 and I cant even run the .exe file for CLion and Intellij IDEA as administrator. However, I am able to run Intellij IDEA with no problem using .\idea.bat in the command line. No error or warning is shown in the command line.

The path of the Intellij IDEA short cut on my desktop is directed to the right idea64.exe file. Anyone have any idea what could be the issue and how I should go about fixing it? Thank you.

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in Windows Log? If you have antivirus/firewall, try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home, IDE executable are excluded from the scan.

Comment: Might also be the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250990 Try mentioned in that issue solution. These are the links: https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe 
https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: Ah thanks but I managed to solve it here. This could help others who encounter a similar problem. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/2876693

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to install the https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe package. it will add needed `vcruntime140.dll` native library.